# Convert json string to objects without key

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, encode

There's a json string without key for each objects like

```
[
    {
        "name": "A",
        "number": 1,
        "age": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "B",
        "number": 2,
        "age": 30
    },
    {
        "name": "C",
        "number": 3,
        "age": 40
    }
]
```

and I only need name and number, so I have a class like below trying to encode the json string into it

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class FooResClass extends BaseResModel {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = -6398045272254450504L;

 private List<AData> aDataList;

  @Data
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
  public class AData {
    @JsonProperty("number")
    private Long number;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
  }
```

then it says

```
jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of
```

am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Your JSON and POJO don't match, and there are several ways to resolve the problem:

- parse JSON as `List<FooResClass.AData>` and then instantiate `FooResClass`;
- define a custom Deserializer (*that allows to reuse the parsing logic and would be a preferred way if you would choose to change the code*);
- change the structure of your JSON.

## Details

Firstly, if `AData` is nested, it should be `static` (otherwise an instance of the enclosing class would be required for instantiation and parsing would fail).

Secondly, the JSON you have represents an Array of JSON-objects that correspond to the `AData` class. I.e. it's not a JSON-object but a JSON-array, which matches a `List<AData>`, but not to the instance of enclosing class `FooResClass`.

For instance, the following parsing would succeed:

```
String json = // your json data
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<AData> aData = mapper.readValue(json,  new TypeReference<List<FooResClass.AData>>(){});
FooResClass fooRes = new FooResClass(aDataList); // assuming that all-args constructor was defined
```

In order to obtain an instance of `FooResClass` with your current code, the JSON should be structured in the following way:

```
{
   "aDataList":[
      {
         "name":"A",
         "number":1,
         "age":20
      },
      {
         ...
      },
      {
         ...
      }
   ]
}
```

If you can't change the structure of the JSON you need to customize the deserialization of the `FooResClass`.

## Deserializer

For that, you can define a custom Deserializer by extending [`StdDeserializer`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/StdDeserializer.html) and overriding its abstract method `deserialize()`.

That's how it might be implemented:

```
public class FooResClassDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<FooResClass> {

    public FooResClassDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public FooResClassDeserializer(Class<FooResClass> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public FooResClass deserialize(JsonParser p,
                                   DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<FooResClass.AData> aDataList = mapper.readValue(p, new TypeReference<>() {});
        return new FooResClass(aDataList);
    }
}
```

To instruct Jackson that this Desirializer should be used while pasing `FooResClass`, you need to annotate this class with [`@JsonDeserialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.htm) and specify the class of Desirializer thought the `using` attribute.

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonDeserialize(using = FooResClassDeserializer.class)
public static class FooResClass extends BaseResModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6398045272254450504L;

    @JsonProperty("aDataList")
    private List<AData> aDataList;

    @Data
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class AData {
        @JsonProperty("number")
        private Long number;
        @JsonProperty("name")
        private String name;
    }
}
```

With this change, you'll be able to parse the current unaltered JSON into an instance of `FooResClass` (*I've tested this solution by removing the* `extends` *clause, since you haven't provided* `BaseResModel` *class*).

Comment: The json data is from another api which I can't modify.

Comment: I'm trying to implement the Deserializer you mentioned now.. thanks.

Comment: @chiefpika I've tested the Desirelizer posted in the Answer against your sample data, and it works fine. It would require some changes only if `BaseResModel` declares properties that you expect to come in the form of JSON. If it's not the case, you can use it as is.

Comment: the "new TypeReference<>()" says "Diamond operator is not applicable for non-parameterized types", I followed everything, not sure if anything went wrong.

Comment: @chiefpika Which version of Java you're using? Try to provide the type explicitly `new TypeReference<List<FooResClass.AData>>() {}`.

Comment: Java 8 because of my team... have no choice. It shows`Type 'jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.TypeReference' does not have type parameters` after changing it into `new TypeReference<List<FooResClass.AData>>() {}`

Comment: @chiefpika Imported `TypeReference` is the wrong one. It should come from the package `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type`, **not** `jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm`.